How do you disable features on building QGIS?
Within QGIS, is there a way to create a build or disable some features, so that when you distribute a build that there is no way a user could effectively use them?
I am new to QGIS, so this might be a noob question, but there are some options we would like to disable  if at all possible.

Database connectivity - specifically SQL server and postgres
Use of external plugins or limited about of repositories by location that can be used.

We would like to turn off these options in our ecosystem, if possible.

I’m voting to close this question because it is a comment on a different Question not a new Question.

Where shall I put the question and this could help someone struggling to set this up on Windows.  Seems like there's more criticism of posts than actual responses.  I mean if we can help each other, shouldn't we?  @Vince

We use a Q&A model. There's no general problem with posting a Question then answering it, though the multiple logins thing offers a source of source of contention (see https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). The thing is, we are not a discussion forum, so the Questions need to be questions and the Answers need to be answers. As original poster (OP), it is your responsibility to make the best Question possible, and posing an Answer that would be better suited as an edit is not the way to accomplish this.

I think you should focus your question on how to disable one of the options you are asking about.  That way you can describe what you've tried and where you're stuck trying to do just that.  Getting that one question answered may mean your other does not need to be asked.

You could absolutely build QGIS without those features. It is an open source project with the code published freely. See: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS
An easier option would be to just disable the features, the QGIS UI can easily be customized using:
Settings> Interface Customization

From there just disable (untick) the plugin menu:

And anything Database/dbManager/PostGIS/SQL Server related.
Also untick the Interface Customization, so it cannot be activated.
Then load the config to any QGIS install. Once restarted the features will be disabled in the interface.
